# ngCordova in Intel XDK

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, intel-xdk

I have recently moved from working with ionic to working with the intel XDK tool.
what i want is to use the ngCordova library that was originaly developed for ionic,
since the plugin is open source, i thought i might try use it in my intel xdk project so i've followed the ngCordova docs and i had no problems untill i had to add the camera plugin.
when i type the command: 
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera

it says that the currect directory is not cordova based even though it is the directory where all my project files are.

does anyone know how i can add plugins(in this case the camera plugin) to my project?

the error i get when i try to run the app on the browser is: camrea is not defined which is a normall error for testing in browser. but it does not work in device either.
im using the code from the ngCordova docs.

Answer (score 0):

The org.apache.cordova.camera plugin is one of the plugins that is added to your project by default, on project creation, within the XDK. You can choose whether or not to include the default Cordova plugins from the Project tab, also. You can also add plugins from the Cordova CLI. This plugin happens to already be included.